# How to check if list2 has all the contents of one of list1's nested lists?

Tags: python

```
`list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
 list2 = [1 ,8 ,7 ,2, 0, 3]`
```

Output should say, that list2 contains all integers in one of list1's sublists.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site isn't a free bespoke coding service. What have you tried so far? Are you getting any error messages or incorrect output? If you're completely new to Python, I'd recommend reading through some introductory tutorials first.

Comment: The reason I'm asking this here is for one, I don't know a better place and two, I didn't find answer to this specific question anywhere else. I'm doing a tic tac toe game and i needed this for checking who won. If you happened to know a site, where I could ask all possible questions about coding, I'd be grateful to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A version that will take duplicates into account:

```
from collections import Counter

list_1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
list_2 = [1, 8, 7, 2, 0, 3]

counts = Counter(list_2)
res = any(len(Counter(e) - counts) == 0 for e in list_1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
True
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are no duplicates in either list:

```
s2 = set(list2)
result = any(all(e in s2 for e in sub) for sub in list1)
```

If there might be duplicates and you need all occurrences to appear in `list2`, you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

c2 = Counter(list2)
result = any(not (Counter(sub) - c2) for sub in list1)
```

Comment: I still doubt that `Counter` is an optimal solution, there should be an option with `set`

Comment: Maybe this `set2 = set(list2) ; any(len(set2.intersection((s := set(l)))) == len(s) for l in list1)` .

Comment: Not if you account for duplicates, I am sure. You will have to track counts.

Comment: Without dupes you can have a set based one-liner: `any(not set(sub).difference(list_2) for sub in list_1)`, but you forfeit the short-circuiting of `all`